# Help understanding "little o" notation

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I have the following homework problem, with given solution but I do not understand why certain choices in the solution were made as opposed to my own (incorrect) solution and I would like some clarification.

The question is to compare the growth rates of several functions using o, O and $\Theta$.  It is the first time I have seen this notation and it is assumed knowledge for the class.

I am given the relation:

$f(n) \leq c.g(n) \Leftrightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 0$.

I have the following function $n\log n$. I am then supposed to compute o$(n \log n)$, according to the solution. As I interpreted the relation above and in the problem I had picked $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ to be the same $n \log n$ and evaluated to find that limit and quickly concluded my answer was incorrect.

The solution sets $f(n)=n^l$, where $l \in \mathbb{N}$ and $g(n)=2^n$ and the proceeds to calculate the limit and shows that it is in fact 0 as $n \rightarrow \infty$. I am fine with calculating the limit, I do not get why $f$ and $g$ were set to be what they were and how I would make this choice in the future, for say a different function not $n \log n$.

Any help in explaining *why* it has to be this way, would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "I have the following function $o(n\log n)$." I don't understand what you're trying to say. That's like saying "I have the following number $<7$." $o$ is a relationship between two functions.

Comment: The assumption that you made is not valid. Having $f(n) \leq c \cdot g(n)$, you cannot say that the limit is zero. Also, it is clear that $f(n)=n^l$ (for constant $l$) is polynomial, while $g(n)=2^n$ is exponential. Exponential $g(n)$ is obviously growing much faster than polynomial $f(n)$, that's why $f(n) \in o(g(n))$.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, sorry that is bad wording on my part.  I mean to say, I was given the following $n \log n$, and I am supposed to use the little o notation o$(n \log n)$ to show that the limit of $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\rightarrow 0 $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @emab, perhaps it is my fault in how I have asked the question, but you haven't understood my problem at all.  I am in full agreement with what you have said.  My question is, given the relation I gave above, and $n \log n$ and told to find o$(n \log n)$, why does the solution proceed to calculate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^l}{2^n}$?  How do they pick $f(n) = n^l$ and $g(n)=2^n$, when they just give, $n \log n$ and the relation I stated in my question.  Does that help make it any clearer?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "use $o(n\log n)$". Again, that's like saying "I'm supposed to use $<7$ to prove..." When you say you need to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f/g = 0$, what are $f$ and $g$?

Comment: @DavidRicherby That is exactly my question!  The sheet simply says, find o$(n \log n)$, states the relation for $f$ and $g$ and then solves the limited using the values of $f$ and $g$ that I stated in my question.  I don't know why the values of $f$ and $g$ they used are assigned.  I am trying to understand, what they are asking me to do and why they took the approach they did to solve it, because it isn't clear to me, which is why I cannot explain it to you. - I'm not unable to solve the limit, once I know what $f$ and $g$ are, but I have no idea how they got $f$ and $g$ from $n \log n$

Comment: If the question literally says, "find $o(n\log n)$", then it is meaningless and you should ask whoever set it for clarification. I'm sorry but there's nothing we can do to help you.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thanks, I will do that then, because I can't make sense of it either, and I thought perhaps it I just because this is a new topic for me, that maybe there was some prior knowledge that I didn't have.

Comment: @Aesir Thanks. This question will probably get closed as "unclear what you're asking." If you need help with the question once it's been clarified to you, you can either edit this one or start a new one.